# powershell regex check if file has word wrapped in special characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to match text in a file that contains a variable wrapped in special characters.

Ex:

```
#{VARIABLE_A}#

#{VARIABLE_A_EXAMPLE}#
```

it should NOT match these

```
#{VARIABLEA}#

#{_VARIABLE_A}#

#{_VARIABLE_A_}#

#{VARIABLE_A

  VARIABLE_A}#

#{}#
#{_}#
```

what I tried

```
#{\w{3}}#
/\w+\#{[}#]+)\)/g
#\\w+\\b
#{\w+}#
```

Can someone explain how the answer is derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
#{[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)+}#
```

If digits are allowed you can add `0-9` into the character classes, or you may use `[^\W_]` that matches any word char other than `_`:

```cs
#{[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+}#
#{[^\W_]+(?:_[^\W_]+)+}#
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%7B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%28%3F%3A_%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%29%2B%7D%23&i=%23%7BVARIABLE_A%7D%23%0D%0A%23%7BVARIABLE_A_EXAMPLE%7D%23%0D%0Ait%20should%20NOT%20match%20these%0D%0A%23%7BVARIABLEA%7D%23%0D%0A%23%7B_VARIABLE_A%7D%23%0D%0A%23%7B_VARIABLE_A_%7D%23%0D%0A%23%7BVARIABLE_A%0D%0A%20%20VARIABLE_A%7D%23%0D%0A%23%7B%7D%23%0D%0A%23%7B_%7D%23).

*Details*

- `#{` - a `#{` substring
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)+` - one or more occurrences of `_` and one or more letters
- `}#` - a `}#` substring

Comment: Hello how would I specifically  match those patterns I DO NOT want to match? like a way to check if they are mistakenly inserted into the file? thanks

Comment: @obumoon Try `#{(?![a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)+}#)[^{}]*}#`

Comment: thanks for that but it matches everything except these incomplete variable missing the starting or ending special characters like #{VARIABLE_A and  VARIABLE_A}#

Comment: @obumoon That is complex, try `#{(?![a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)+}#)[^{}]*}#|(?<!#{[^{}]*)(?>[^{}]*})#|#{(?>[^{}]*)(?!}#)`